# Tienda in Tienda León

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Tienda León is a major bus line in Argentina.

I thought the words *tienda* in Spanish and *store* in English were roughly equivalent, but it's hard to imagine a bus line called Bear Store.

I'm curious if:

- *tienda* has a much broader meaning than *store*, and what that is
- something in Tienda León's history gave it that name
- it's not really that unusual, I could start a bus line and call it Bear Store

Comment: Do you mean "lion" instead of "bear"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Tienda León" is the compound last name of one of the founders of the company, as you can read [in the history of the company transcribed below](https://www.tiendaleonmdq.com/):

> 1927, en aquel lejano Buenos Aires, se cruzan coches a caballo, antiguas chatas de carga y los automóviles comienzan a surcar sus calles. Es el momento en que nace lo que hoy es Manuel Tienda León.
>
> Con coraje emprendedor y clara visión de futuro, Don José Tienda Gutiérrez junto a su hijo **Manuel Tienda León** inician la empresa para el transporte de escolares, orientándose luego a la actividad del transporte contratado.
>
> Su primer cliente fue el Colegio de las Religiosas Adoratrices. Más tarde, por pedido de la empresa aérea Cruzeiro de Sul, comienza el traslado de los pasajeros de esa compañía entre el centro de la ciudad y el Aeródromo de Morón.
>
> Desde entonces, el crecimiento de Manuel Tienda León es incesante. En nivel de servicios. En volumen de su flota. En la cantidad de personas transportadas. En la calidad de atención y profesionalismo de su gente.
>
> Hoy, Manuel Tienda León es sinónimo del mejor servicio de traslado en buses y remises. Una trayectoria consagrada en el tiempo y que se proyecta exitosamente hacia el futuro.
>
> Nuestros valores. Cortesía, confiabilidad, agilidad, responsabilidad, eficacia, participación y creatividad conforman una filosofía empresaria que hace del cliente la prioridad número uno en todo momento.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in @Gustavson answer (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37336/17295), Manuel Tienda León was the name of one of the founders, so they're using his Surnames for his Buses company.

It's very common in Spanish to use the surname of the founder for the name of a business or store. In this case it can sound really strange, but we have in Spanish a lot of 'strange' surnames:

- Toponymic surnames: They derive from the name of the place where the person or family associated with the surname lived, came from or owned land. Ex: Albacete (City), Bailén (City), España (Country).
- Geographical surnames: They derive from the name of geographical accidents, or natural things. Ex: Colina (Hill), Monte (Mount), Lago/Lagos (Lake/Lakes), Cueva/Cuevas (Cave).
- Derived from the flora: Rosa (Rose), Granado (Pomegranate), Peral (Pear tree).
- Derived from the fauna: León (Lion), Águila (Eagle), Cordero (Lamb).
- Derived from Architectural items: Pozo (Well), Iglesia (Church), Plaza (Square), Torre (Tower)

**Source:**
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apellido#Apellidos_topon%C3%ADmicos

Comment: There are also many last names related to physical features (Delgado, Rubio, Blanco, Negro, Calvo), professions (Zapatero, Cantero, Labrador, Escudero, Herrero, Barbero, Sacristán, Pastor), and last but not least, last names formed by adding -ez to a first name to mean "son / daughter to...": Fernando + -ez=Fernández, Pedro + -ez=Pérez, Rodrigo + -ez=Rodríguez, Ramiro + -ez=Ramírez, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew about the relation of the '-ez' in the names.